# Flutter bad practice to execute functions inside Widget build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to listen to the current theme permanently because I had some issues with the systemchrom, so I found a workaround for that where I call a BlocProvider.of inside my Widget build. In general, it works perfectly fine now, but is this a clean solution or not a good practice, if last, is there a better way of listening to a SystemUiOverlayStyle permanently?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
BlocProvider.of<SysUiCubit>(context).changeTheme(context, isDarkMode);
 return BlocBuilder<SysUiCubit, SysUiState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
```

I added a small logic inside the build so the BlocProvider only gets called when the theme changes:

```
bool buildOnce =false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isDarkMode = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
    if(!buildOnce){
      setPrev(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark);
    buildOnce=true;
    }
    if(darkmodePrev != isDarkMode){
      BlocProvider.of<SysUiCubit>(context).changeTheme(context, isDarkMode);
      buildOnce=false;
    }
```

Same thing I asked myself on another point at my app:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todo= context.watch<TodoListCubit>().state.todo;

    return BlocListener<TodoListCubit, TodoListState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
```

Here I have a todo list where I call `context.watch` inside my build function - same question - I didn't find a cleaner solution for updating the todo list every time the widget rebuilds, so is this okay or a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

##### Bad Practice

Defining a `function` inside the `build`

##### Good Practice (To be followed)

Define a `function` outside the `build` and call it inside the function which will help you `rebuild` the widget if needed.

---

For your problem, I suggest you emit changes when the `theme` changes and rebuild the widget using `buildWhen` instead of embedding this work around inside the build.

That would be considered more cleaner code, If this is what you are looking for.

---

Use something like, example from the official [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/example):

```
class ThemeCubit extends Cubit<ThemeData> {
  /// {@macro brightness_cubit}
  ThemeCubit() : super(_lightTheme);

  static final _lightTheme = ThemeData(
    floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  );

  static final _darkTheme = ThemeData(
    floatingActionButtonTheme: const FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
    ),
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  );

  /// Toggles the current brightness between light and dark.
  void toggleTheme() {
    emit(state.brightness == Brightness.dark ? _lightTheme : _darkTheme);
  }
}
```

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  buildWhen: (previousState, state) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not //  add your logic here
    // to rebuild the widget with state
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

Comment: Please find the updated post, hope it helps

Comment: Never used buldWhen before so this is completly wrong isnt it? :
`buildWhen: (prevState, state){
        bool isDarkMode = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;
        if(!buildOnce){
          setPrev(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark);
          buildOnce=true;
        }
        if(darkmodePrev != isDarkMode){
          BlocProvider.of<SysUiCubit>(context).changeTheme(context, isDarkMode);
          buildOnce=false;
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      }`

Comment: I think my problem is, I dont call the BloCProvider somewhere else again only inside widget build, so when I remove this, BlocBuild will not rebuild anyway

Comment: I wouldn't say It is not complelty wrong, i would rather say , using `buildwhen` your code would be more clean and you follow the industry standards and more importantly you can avoid using the work around inside the build method

Comment: Any reference on why is it bad to define functions inside the build method?